# Nginx: Is there a way to prioritise requests from a specific IP address?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, debian-squeeze

We have a public website that also serves requests for an internal system (on a dedicated IP address). When the website gets busy, and the server load increases, all requests slow down. This is acceptable for the public site, but not for the internal system.

In Nginx (or Debian Linux), is there a way to prioritise requests such that the internal system requests would get priority?

Please do not suggest increasing the server size, caching, or similar useless suggestions.

For reference:

- Debian Squeeze
- Nginx
- PHP-FPM

Comment: If they were so useless, we wouldn't need to suggest them, and you wouldn't need to mention them.

Comment: I've had enough experience to know that people often suggest options that really don't answer te question at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Long answer: Clustering is your friend. It's quite obvious the server you have the website on isn't enough for the load you're placing on it.

Comment: Thanks for the short answer. We are moving to clustering, but I was hoping there was a more immediate, short term solution to buy us some time.

Answer (score 0):

You cant prioritise, but you can limit external request and allow all internal request or from some ip, maybe whit limit_req and proxy pass, but likk Nathan say make a cluster is the easy way.

Comment: The problem is knowing what to limit the requests to. We can easily handle 40+ req/sec sometimes, and only 10req/sec other times.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible to "prioritize" by pinning resources, with a little effort.

1. Launch 2 separate `nginx` instances
2. Use `CPUAffinity` to pin some CPUs on each (like 90% CPUs to public, 10% to private).

This ways, you make sure that some resources are always reserved/prioritized to specific process (here a specific `nginx` process).

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Scheduling